# How to publish versioned JavaDoc/Site to github pages in Java project?

Tags: java, maven, github, github-pages

If a project is named `foo`, I want to publish Javadocs for different versions separate directories, like:

`me.github.io/foo/1.0/apidocs/`
`me.github.io/foo/2.0/apidocs/`

The similar problem is discussed here: https://github.com/github/maven-plugins/issues/22 but it doesn't seem that the problem is solved

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I use [javadoc.io](http://www.javadoc.io) for hosting javadoc for my open source projects on Github, and then link to that from the readme.md and github pages (e.g. here is the javdoc for the latest version of one of my projects : http://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.aol.simplereact/simple-react/0.99.2).

It's simple enough to set up. Once you've released to Maven Central or bintray (including your sources) browse to

```
http://www.javadoc.io/doc/<group id>/<artefact id>/<version>
```

That will get your library added to the system and it should download the javadoc and add it to the site within a day (sometimes immediately).

It's better than managing the process yourself, and it is guaranteed to match the actual version of the code that people are using (and the source they'll see in their IDEs), as it is downloaded from the same version repo in Maven Central. (If you manage your own, the possibility of uploading subtely different versions to Maven Central and your hosting site emerges).

Comment: Thanks; didn't know about this service. Interesting, if it respects javadoc exclusions - If I have quite a lot of classes, which are not a part of API and made public only because there is no "friend" classes in Java.

Comment: Seems it does. Probably it just picks javadoc.jar from the maven distribution, and if some classes are filtered in that jar, they are filtered on the site.

Comment: @john-mcclean, but what if a project doesn't use maven or any build tools? For example, consider my repo: http://github.com/ramswaroop/Algorithms-and-Data-Structures-in-Java, how to host javadocs for this kind of repo?

Comment: @Ramswaroop You can use the builtin GitHub tool to create a Git Hub pages website (which will appear at the following address https://ramswaroop.github.io/Algorithms-and-Data-Structures-in-Java) .If you aren't publishing the library to Maven Nexus Repo or Bin Tray you could generate the javadoc locally and then check it in somewhere on the branch named 'gh-pages' (that github pages will create). You can then link to your javadoc from your website. It's not as nice / automated way to do things, but for examples and non-mavenized projects it should be ok. ( See https://pages.github.com/).

Comment: @JohnMcClean Yes, I am aware of github pages. Just wanted an automated method as in javadocs.io but no issues. Anyways, thank you very much for a detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

https://docshoster.org/ would be another similar option. It has automatic update from maven but also supports direct uploads with api. That means it can be integrated into a build process for example.